# UITableViewCell not holding its selected state

Tags: iphone

I have User Settings view and have a table to list the options.

When the user taps on a cell, the option is selected.

I am saving the option to the property list when the view disappears and till this it is working fine.

But when the user comes to the screen again, i want to have the already selected option to be highlighted(selected);

I tried setting cell.selected = TRUE and also [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES] but the cell is losing its selected state.

I can see the cell getting selected and also  deselected?

How can i make a particular cell hold its selected state when the view loads?

Answer (score 1):

In the Human Interface Guidelines, Apple recommends that you don't use "selected" for representing state, and use an accessory view instead.

I ignored this at first, but then noticed that use of selected has somewhat unpredictable results from 2.2.1 to 3.0 (behavior changed without me changing any code), so I went with their recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the selection of a particular cell by its indexPath on tableView, and not directly on the cell.

So, you need to set the method:

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

this might work, instead of changing the cell state. =D